# Lightview to open link on page load using jQuery

Tags: jquery, load, lightbox

I would like to have jQuery open a particular YouTube video pop up when the page loads using the Lightview plugin: (http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/lightview).

Any ideas on the code to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
     {

    Lightview.show({
url: 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/kBqj7GjN4Mo?autoplay=1&autohide=1&border=0&egm=0&showinfo=0&showsearch=0',
type: 'iframe',
options: {
width: 638,
height: 360,
viewport: 'scale'
}
});


    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple, use this form of code:

```
$(function(){
    //Your lightbox code
});
```

whatever is in the `function` will be called when the page finished loading.